# Firebase Custom Claims security rules database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Hi i would like to ask if in firebase it is possible to add custom Claims like that:

```
 {
    roles:["ROLE_A","ROLE_B"]
 }
```

And at the same time write correct realtime databse security rules like :

```
".read": "auth.token.roles.contains('ROLE_A')
```

This is my databse example:

```
"root":{
    "users":{
       "nodeA":{
           
        }
       "nodeB":{
        
        }
     }
  }
```

When i try to wryte the rule i have

[image]

the same thing works with someting like that

[image]

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Did you give it a try yet?

Comment: hi @FrankvanPuffelen, yes i tried but it doesn't seem to work, are there maybe problems with managing arrays or lists in realtime db security rules?

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to work" Please edit your question in that case to include the [minimum, complete/standalone code, rules and data that any of us can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that it'll be much harder to help.

Comment: You're right, thanks for helping!

Comment: You're missing the `token` property from the code in your question in your playground screenshots. I'm pretty sure it should be `auth.token.customClaims`...

Comment: i've used custom auth object in simulation without token object. You can se the object that i used in picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work. Just have in mind that the custom claims have a limit in size of `1000 bytes`. If you need to save to many roles that could break your app authorization logic.

I like to use the custom claims for very basic roles like `isAdmin` and the rest over the datbase. You can change the custom claims only form a secured backend and in Firebase that is probably a cloud function. You would need to save those roles in a database for your forntend to see what roles a user has or not and sync those with the users custom claims. That data needs to be secured for users authorized to change them. When you already have that you can also use the same data from the database to write your database rules. It's also very easy to sync them between both databases.